# Can't click the object inside 'li' ng-repeat in protractor

Tags: protractor

I am very new to protractor, facing problem to click the object inside 'li' ng-repeat in protractor. Any suggestion would greatly help ...

My code in the spec.js, it pulls up the page, login & success in getting the title too. But failed to click the object "LOG FETCH TOOLS". with msg "Failed: No element found using locator: By(link text, LOG FETCH TOOLS)"

```
describe('Tools Home Page', function() {
beforeEach(function() {
return browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
});

this.title = 'Diagnostic Tools';
it('should have a title', function() {

    browser.driver.get('https://URL');
    browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
    browser.driver.findElement(by.id('username')).sendKeys('user');
    browser.driver.findElement(by.id('password')).sendKeys('pass123');
    browser.driver.findElement(by.name('login')).click();
    browser.waitForAngular();
    expect(browser.getTitle()).toContain('Diagnostic Tools');
    element(by.linkText("LOG FETCH TOOLS")).click();
    });
});
```

Object location :

```
<i><li ng-repeat="(key, value) in tools | groupBy: 'group'" class="ng-scope">
<a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#group-0" ng-    click="toggleIcon($index)" class="ng-binding collapsed">
            <i id="grp-0" class="fa fa-plus-circle" ng-class="collapseBtn ? 'fa-minus-circle' : 'fa-plus-circle'" style=""></i>
 LOG FETCH TOOLS
</a>
<ul id="group-0" class="nav nav-second-level group collapse" style="height: 0px;">
<!-- ngRepeat: tool in value | orderBy: 'disp_name' | filter: search --><li id="tool-40" ng-repeat="tool in value | orderBy: 'disp_name' | filter: search" class="ng-scope">
              <a ui-sref="tools.detail({id: tool.id})" ui-sref-active="selected" title="Crawl Logs From Ep Till Smm:- This tool crawls log starting from the entered Entry Point IP till it reaches the SMM machines." class="ng-binding" href="#/tools/detail/40">
                Crawl Logs From Ep Till Smm
              </a>
```

Comment: Isn't it AngularJS application? as you mentioned browser.ignoreSynchronization = true; in your script. If it is Angular application, you should not use browser.ignoreSynchronization = true in your code. And seems to problem with element locator. Change the locator. to -.by.xpath(".//a[contains(text(),'LOG FETCH TOOLS')]")

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Before login it's non-angular, post login it's AngularJS app. An how for I removed beforeEach. And tried with xpath, not working. Msg throws "No element found using locator: By(xpath, .//a[contains(text(),'LOG FETCH TOOLS')])"  .  element(by.xpath(".//a[contains(text(),'LOG FETCH TOOLS')]")).click();

Comment: Thanks Suresh. Before login it's non-angular, post login it's AngularJS app. Any how I removed beforeEach. And tried with xpath, not working. I am trying : element(by.xpath(".//a[contains(text(),'LOG FETCH TOOLS')]")).click();  Still it gives "No element found using locator: By(xpath, .//a[contains(text(),'LOG FETCH TOOLS')])" .

Comment: after login you should make browser.ignoreSynchronization=false as it Angular App post login

Comment: Can you share the Website? Once your problem is solve make it  browser.driver.get('https://URL'); again.

Will be good to Try at my end, if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `cssContainingText` for such scenarios-

```
element(by.cssContainingText('a[href="#"]', 'LOG FETCH TOOLS')).click();
```

Give it a try it should work!

Answer (score 0):

instead of `by.linkText` try using `by.partialLinktext`. The anchor tag may have some leading white spaces in it.so by.linktext wont work in such situations.

Comment: no, this also says no element found. browser.findElement(by.partialLinkText("LOG FETCH TOOLS")).click();